# Boost Subgraph and Bundled properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm using bundled properties and adjacency_list and would like to use the subgraph class.

```
struct Vertex
{
   int index;
   int seed;
}; 

struct Edge
{
 bool visted;
 double weight;
};

typedef adjacency_list<listS, listS, undirectedS, Vertex, property<edge_index_t,int,Edge> > Graph;
typedef subgraph<Graph> testSubgraph;
```

The `property<edge_index_t,int,Edge>` part is needed, as subgraph needs `edge_index_t` to compare two edges.

Now my question is how do I add an Edge using bundled properties in a Subgraph? 
In the normal graph without `property<edge_index_t,int,Edge>` I add an edge as following:

```
Edge e;
vertex_descriptor u,v; 
// fill in u and v;
e.weight = 1.0;
e.visted=false;
add_edge(u,v,e,graph);
```

But this doesn't work for Subgraph.

Hope someone knows a solution for this.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the a similar issue when trying to add a vertex with the `add_vertex()` function and found that there is a (very old) unresolved issue on the boost bugtracker:

[Ticket #380: Support for bundled properties in graph adaptors](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/380):

> The graph adaptors (such as subgraph) do not support bundled 
>   properties, but they should.

---

Further searching lead to the following 2 patches, which are not yet merged but appear to finally bring the support for bundled properties in subgraphs:

- [Ticket #10708: Property support in add_vertex() method for subgraph](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10708)
- [Ticket #10709: Graph bundled property support in subgraph](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10709)

So I guess the answer is: For now, don't use bundled properties. But in the future, the issue should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

An adjacency list do not have edge_index:es. You need to assign an index yourself, but that is as simple as adding a `size_t index` to the `Edge`, and assigning an index as you create the edges.

You probably do not need to create edges for the subgraph, since the boost subgraphs are induced subgraphs. Therefore, all edges in the graph of which both endpoints are in the subgraph will be included in your subgraphs.

Comment: If I just add size_t index to my Edge struct it still won't find this index, as it is needed in 'propertey<edge_index_t, int, ... >'

Answer (score 0):

I am also just learning BGL and the following code works for adding the bundled edge property within the `add_edge` call.

```
boost::add_edge(vd1, vd2, testSubgraph::edge_property_type{0, Edge{/* ... */}}, graph);
```

`0` is a dummy edge index and, according to my experience, it is overwritten with the proper edge index by BGL. I don't know whether that's always true (any comment welcome).

You can also just add the edge to the subgraph without using the bundle and use the edge descriptor returned by `add_edge` to add the properties later.

```
auto pair = boost::add_edge(vd1, vd2, graph);
boost::put(boost::get(&Edge::member_name1, graph), pair.first, member_value1);
/* ... */
```

Don't know whether it is possible to `put` a complete property bundle using the second method.